# Tool for advanced dds image editing

Tags: windows, gratis, images, image-editor, image-editing

The [dds file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectDraw_Surface) is a raster picture format like png or bmp.

There are several free editors for that format, but the one I’m looking for should feature brightness and contrast editing for the whole image *(I have a set of about 400 rather dark images that I would like to make brighter)*. So as there are lot of files, it should also feature in‑place editing with mipmaps version included.
A color picker would be a bonus.

An another requirement come from the fact dds image can feature transparency *(alpha channel)* in a similar way of png.
I know most picture editors that can process png tend to turn transparency pixels into white prixel. Keeping transparency is a strong requirement in my case.

I also wouldn’t mind about using something that run on android. In all cases, I don’t want to compile anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net), was the thing I needed.

While it can’t load mipmaps, it’s autolevel feature allowed me bright pictures while keeping more quickly *(this avoid the typical white layer added by an increased brightness setting)*.

Comment: I’ll accept an another answer if it provide a way to load mipmaps as a separate files.